# Minimize using semidefinite programming

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have the following optimization problem in $Q \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$

$$\text{minimize} \quad \mbox{Tr}(CQ) + \|Q\|_1$$

where $\| \cdot \|_1$ denotes the sum of absolute values of the matrix entries. How to write an equivalent optimization problem in SDP form?

Comment: Please define your variables...

Comment: Here Q is the optimization variable of size of m*n and C is the given matrix of size n*m.

Comment: What is "||Q|| Q "? Please use mathjax.

Comment: Why SDP? Why not write as a linear program? Did you forget to mention any constraints?